Can OpenSearch data-prepper be deployed in k8s deployment with multiple replicas without causing duplication in target / sink system?
I am planning to send logs to OpenSearch cluster on AWS using data-prepper log ingestion pipeline.
I am thinking of deploying data-prepper inside an EKS cluster. I could find example here ; but it shows data-prepper running as a single docker container on MiniKube.
Wondering if I can deploy data-prepper with multiple replicas in a K8S cluster? If done so, will they read / send duplicate log data to OpenSearch?
